# Как обновить php до 7.1 на mac os?

Tags: php, macos, mac

Команда

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.1
```

не помогла.
До этого пытался обновить до 7.0 но он работает только после команды

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

и то только в этой сессии командной строки. Стоит только открыть новую вкладку сразу будет 5.6

Как обновить перманентно php до 7.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

```
$ brew install php71
==> Installing php71 from homebrew/php
.......
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.8_20: 349 files, 39.5MB
$ php -v
PHP 7.1.8 (cli) (built: Aug  7 2017 15:02:45) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

Может быть понадобится сделать что-то из тех инструкций, которые выводятся вместо многоточия выше. Для работы консольной версии должно хватить добавить  в `~/.profile` указанную в инструкциях строку.

Comment: Там еще могут понадобиться манипуляции с `$PATH`.

Comment: Да, про них это строку в `.profile` нужно добавить

Comment: Спасибо! Работает